# How do you initialize an array of ninety '0's' in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, initialization

I'm trying to initialize an array in matlab of ninety zero's. However, I don't want to write 90 consecutive zeros after even = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...... ] etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you find an answer which you like, please **accept** it. For more information, check out the [FAQ on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`zeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/zeros.html) function.

E.g. `x = zeros(1,90)`

Comment: What about an array of ninety 42's? That is, is there a *general form* of zeros?

Comment: @pst: Use the `ones` function. `x = 42*ones(1,90)`.

Comment: @pst: `42 * ones(1,90)`.  Or `repmat([1], 1, 90)`.

Comment: @pst: This is how we generate matrices of a single number. For more complicated replication, we use `repmat`.

Comment: @ Ben: you mean `repmat([42], 1, 90)` :)

Comment: @Smash, @Ben: The `[]` is not required ; `repmat(42,1,90)`.

Comment: @Jacob shoudln't that be `x = 42.*ones(1,90)`? (`.*` instead of `*`)